# When where and how to use ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a student working on a mvc project to move a site from coldfusion to .net mvc. Were are also redesigning the site in the process so I am working with other team members, the design team members have a basic understanding of razor, but aren't expected to know any other parts of the framework.

I've always tried to use `ViewBag` as little as possible, now even more so because the designers don't know what is in the `ViewBag` when building the views, and get no intellisense.

Since working on this project I've moved to using the `ViewBag` only in the baseController for the project adding properties in the `OnActionExecuted` So that every view will have the same `ViewBag` Properties. I've also tried to only use `ViewBag` properties in layouts.

Since doing this I've wondered what are good reasons for ever adding to the ViewBag in a controller action directly before calling the view. I've come to appreciate that making more ViewModels while slightly more time helps to inform exactly what a view should be doing, as well as adds clarity.

I wanted to know when other people used `ViewBag` where they found it appropriate and what they used to it for. I can't think of using it any time outside of a basecontroller now, I was hoping to get insight into other uses for the `ViewBag` that perhaps I am just missing. Should I ever be adding to the ViewBag directly before calling an action, or should I create a more robust viewModel in these cases?

Comment: FWIW I had some subtle bugs happen because of I miss typed a property name on a `ViewBag`. You get zero indication that anything is wrong unless you happen to visually see something missing on the page. Too easy to miss. Too easy to go wrong. I just don't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ViewBag is essentially a Dictionary, except that the syntax is a bit cleaner.  Instead of writing

```
myDict["SomeProperty"]
```

you can access the dynamic dictionary's elements with first-class dot notation:

```
myViewBag.SomeProperty
```

Because `ViewBag` is a property of `ControllerBase`, it provides a convenient place for storing key/value pairs during controller operations, using a first-class syntax. You would use it anytime you need to send key/value pairs to a View, and you want the convenience and clean syntax of a `dynamic` dictionary.

`ViewBag` derives from [`DynamicViewData`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Internal/DynamicViewData.cs), which gives it some useful properties.  For example:

```
// Implementing this function extends the ViewBag contract, supporting or improving some scenarios. For example
// having this method improves the debugging experience as it provides the debugger with the list of all
// properties currently defined on the object.
public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
{
    return ViewData.Keys;
}
```

In general, I would favor strongly-typed `ViewModel` objects over the `ViewBag` or `ViewData` dictionaries, since strongly-typed objects give you compile-time type safety.  This is especially true if you have complex structured data to pass to the View.

**See Also**
[ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)